# Exclude elements with special class from jquery function

Tags: jquery

I use a function to add a class to a td-element for an hover-effect:

```
    $("#document-table tr").hover(function() {
    if $('tr:has(td.nodrag)'){
    return false;   
    } else {
    $(this.cells[0]).addClass('showDragHandle');
}, function() {
    $(this.cells[0]).removeClass('showDragHandle');
});
```

});

Example for tr

```
<tr class="nodrag"></tr>
```

Now, I want to exclude all tr with the class nodrag. Actually, it throws an error: *Unexpected identifier*

What´s wrong? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `:not` selector on the tr.

```
$('#document-table tr:not(".nodrag")').hover(function() {
    $(this.cells[0]).addClass('drag');
  }, 
  function(){$(this.cells[0]).removeClass('drag');}
);
```

see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEq55/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on your jquery object:

```
.not('tr.nodrag')
```

or:

```
.filter(':not(tr.nodrag)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:hover` psudo-class in CSS to do this without any javascript code required

Answer (score 0):

You can also check using the [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method. This would boild your if statement down to something like this:

`if ( $("tr").hasClass("nodrag") ) { ... }`